# How to access replaced procedure after FastcodeAddressPatch

Tags: delphi

I tried to replace Delphi build-in function with my own version on-the-fly.

```
function ShortCutToTextOverride(ShortCut: TShortCut): string;
begin
  if SomeCondition then
    Result := Menus.ShortCutToText // after patching the pointer equals ShortCutToTextOverride
  else
  begin
    // My own code goes here
  end;
end;

FastcodeAddressPatch(@Menus.ShortCutToText, @ShortCutToTextOverride);
```

After patching, the original function is no longer accessible. 
It is possible access it anyway?

Comment: If you want reliable code hooking for win32 (x64 is still under development) then I'd recommend madCodeHook: http://madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm

Comment: You can use something [`like this`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6003579/960757) as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid not: the first bytes are overwritten by a jump to the new function.

You can use KOLDetours.pas: it returns the pointer to the trampoline (original first few bytes that are overwritten by the detour).
http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/source/browse/trunk/SRC/KOLDetours.pas

For example:

```
type
  TNowFunction = function:TDatetime;
var
  OrgNow: TNowFunction;
function NowExact: TDatetime;
begin
  //exact time using QueryPerformanceCounter
end; 

initialization
  OrgNow := KOLDetours.InterceptCreate(@Now, @NowExact);
  Now()     -> executes NowExact() 
  OrgNow()  -> executes original Now() before the hook
```

Comment: KOLDetours works perfectly for 32bit compiler, but have some problems with 64bit compiler. I have not found any updates on 64bit.

Comment: I found a patched version `Cromis.Detours` is compatible with x64. I hope the information is helpful to you all.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 are you sure it is working on 64bit? Because it is the same unit (copy of koldetours) with no changes for handling 64bit specific stuff. Or can you post a link to the patched version?

Comment: Here is the link https://code.google.com/p/native-look-vcl/ I was managed use KOLDetours to get it work. But my application failed to be compiled at x64 platform, until I switched to Cromis.Detours. Its original homepage can be searched in Google.

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 ok so it compiles but does it also work in 64bit? I doubt it does...

Comment: Yes, the code compiles (and also works with) `Cromis.Detours`. Sorry for late reply.